# ¿Cómo puedo extraer texto entre una barra y el segundo guion?

Tags: bash

Tengo la siguiente expresión:

```
feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye
```

Quiero coger lo que hay después de la barra `"/"` y lo que hay antes del segundo guión `"-"`. Es decir:

```
ASD-123
```

Otro ejemplo. De: `asjdhajdsha/asdasda-42342-sdkjhf-skjdhf-cha` quiero obtener `asdasda-42342`.

No sé nada de regex y de momento tengo esto:

```
echo "feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye" | cut -d / -f 2
```

Que me da lo siguiente:

```
ASD-123-hello-goodbye
```

¿Alguien sabría hacer esto?

Answer (score 3):

¡Ibas bien! Solamente necesitabas pasar el resultado a otro `cut`:

```
echo "cadena" | cut -d/ -f2 | cut -d- -f-2
```

Con tus ejemplos:

```
$ cut -d/ -f2 <<< feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye | cut -d- -f-2
ASD-123
$ cut -d/ -f2 <<< asjdhajdsha/asdasda-42342-sdkjhf-skjdhf-cha | cut -d- -f-2
asdasda-42342
```

---

Dado que tienes formato de fichero, puedes utilizar `basename` para que te devuelve el nombre del fichero quitándole la ruta. Después, usas `cut` normalmente:

```
echo "cadena" | basename | cut -d- -f-2
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ basename feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye | cut -d- -f-2
ASD-123
```

---

También se puede hacer con `awk` en un solo comando:

```
awk -F'-|/' '{print $2 "-" $3}'
```

Esto "rompe" la cadena en bloques separados por "/" o "-" e imprime el 2.º y 3.º:

```
$ awk -F'-|/' '{print $2 "-" $3}' <<< asjdhajdsha/asdasda-42342-sdkjhf-skjdhf-cha
asdasda-42342
$ awk -F'-|/' '{print $2 "-" $3}' <<< feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye
ASD-123
```

Comment: Gracias!!! todo perfecto

Comment: @JosepCao ¡qué bien! Puedes echar una ojeada a [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Doble awk:

```
echo "feature/ASD-123-hello-goodbye" |awk -F'/' '{print $2}'|awk -F'-' '{print $1"-"$2}'
```

El primer awk toma el caracter `"\"` como delimitador e imprime el segundo campo (todo lo que está después del `/`).

El segundo awk recibe la salida del primero y toma el caracter `"-"` como delimitador, y solo imprime la primera y segunda columna.

Comment: Por favor revisa [answer] , esta publicación no explica nada, te recomiendo agregar como solucionaría lo que se indica en la pregunta.

Comment: El primer awk toma el caracter "\" como delimitador e imprime el elsegundo campo (Todo lo que está después del "/"). El segundo awk recibe la salida del primero y toma el caracter "-" como delimitador, y solo imprime la primera y segunda columna   . Edite el comentario porque me confundi con otra respuesta que había dado

Comment: Ok Mariano, lo tendré en cuenta